Updating material3 dependencies breaks Jetpack Compose @Preview
When creating a new Jetpack Compose project, the default dependency for Material3 is: implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
However, after updating the dependecy to: implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1") the @Preview for Compose breaks and I'm getting a following error:

Android Studio's detailed view shows this:
Render problem
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x1060060.
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1161)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1137)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1141)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColorStateList(Resources_Delegate.java:264)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColor(Resources_Delegate.java:242)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:1065)
    at androidx.compose.material3.ColorResourceHelper.getColor-WaAFU9c(DynamicTonalPalette.android.kt:205)
    at androidx.compose.material3.DynamicTonalPaletteKt.dynamicLightColorScheme34(DynamicTonalPalette.android.kt:307)
    at androidx.compose.material3.DynamicTonalPaletteKt.dynamicLightColorScheme(DynamicTonalPalette.android.kt:170)
    at com.****.app.ui.theme.ThemeKt.****Theme(Theme.kt:50)
    at com.****.app.ui.login.LoginScreenKt.LoginFormPreview(LoginScreen.kt:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposableMethod(ComposableInvoker.jvm.kt:181)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable(ComposableInvoker.jvm.kt:221)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:504)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:502)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:539)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:497)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.android.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:444)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:443)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:438)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:124)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:497)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:494)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3302)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3235)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:725)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1071)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial(Composition.kt:633)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:619)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1289)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:164)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:322)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:199)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1364)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21291)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3491)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:54)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:365)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


Similar thing happens when I try to update this dependency as well:
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00")) into implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.04.01"))
I have double checked the official documentation for Material3 dependencies.
I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3
Gradle file looks like this:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Default
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.6")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-adaptive-navigation-suite:1.0.0-alpha06")

    // Downloadable Fonts
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-text-google-fonts:1.6.6")

    // Navigation (Compose)
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")

    // Network layer
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
//    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0")

    // Test & Debug
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

Edit
After some more digging it appears that the newer Material3 versions break the dynamic color scheme.
When creating an empty project, in Theme.kt colorScheme value is assigned like this:
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

When I change this block of code to val colorScheme = LightColorScheme, then the @Preview starts working again.

I'm pissed that Google hasn't fixed this yet. It's been 3 months now. It feels awful that I can't roll back to older versions since I have transitive dependencies that force-updates material3 to v1.2.1 whose dynamic color impl is broken.
